# Initial condition for a sequence converges satisfying simple recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_1 = r$ is a positive real number and for each $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2}{n!}$. Note that there is a positive number $\gamma$ so that $r<\gamma$ implies the convergence of the sequence and $r>\gamma$ implies the divergence of the sequence.

> QUESTION 1. Determine what happen if $r=\gamma$.

> QUESTION 2. Try to find some characteristics of the number $\gamma$. For example, can you determine if $\gamma$ is rational or not?

I was making an exercise which asks if the students can manage the induction principle to prove some properties of sequence defined through a recurrence relation. For example if $r=2$, the above sequence converges to zero and to show this is an easy exercise. If $r=3$, the above sequence diverges to infinity and to show this is a medium hard exercise. This two exercises can be done without any linearizations.

Although these exercises are successful, shortly after that, there arose a question about the property of $\gamma$ as described in the above. I have made some little efforts but cannot succeed to find the answers.

Take time. This question is not in much emergency. I wrote this post just because of curiosity. At my opinion, the number $\gamma$ do not have any mathematical importance and it may be hopeless to answer the third question.

For your convenience, I put some informations which I have found.
One can readily find the expression
$$ a_n = \left( \frac{r}{\exp \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\ln k!}{2^k}} \right)^{2^{n-1}} $$
by linearizing the relation by taking logarithm which asserts that the expression for the number
$$ \gamma = e^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\ln k!}{2^k}}  \approx 2.7612$$

Wishing your happy day, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got the answer! (and thank you for asking the question in such a helpful form) Notice that when $r=\gamma$, then your formula for $a_n$ gives
$$
\log a_n = 2^{n-1} \bigg( \log \gamma - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\ln k!}{2^k} \bigg) = 2^{n-1} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{\ln k!}{2^k} > \frac12\ln n!
$$
(since the terms are all nonnegative), which tends to infinifty with $n$. Therefore $a_n$ diverges when $r=\gamma$.

As for $\gamma$ itself, you can check that the given formula is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\gamma = \prod_{k=2}^\infty (k!)^{1/2^k} &= \prod_{k=2}^\infty \prod_{j=2}^k j^{1/2^k} \\
&= \prod_{j=2}^k j^{\sum_{k=j}^\infty 1/2^k} = \prod_{j=2}^\infty j^{1/2^{j-1}} = 2^{1/2}3^{1/4}4^{1/8}5^{1/16}\dots.
\end{align*}
I imagine this is a transcendental (hence irrational) number, but it's certainly not easy to prove.

Comment: Amazing! Using Mathematica I found a closed form $$\gamma=e^{-2 \text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}\approx 2.761206841957499$$

Comment: Many thanks for the author and Raffaele.